# Room: how to convert to SQLite method to Dao's @Query

Tags: android, android-view

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  The below method runs a database method that uses a "for" loop to update a Sort order column of index values.  If there are 9 CardViews in the List, then the the Sort order column will have values starting from 9 and descending to 1.

```
public void resetSortIndexes() {

    int index = List.size();
    for (ListItem s : List) {
        s.setSortorder(index);         
        // update the SQLite database with the new, 
        // descending Sort numbers.   
        sqLiteDB.updateSortIndexes(s);                   
        index--;
    }
}

Database
...
public void updateSortIndexes (ListItem item) { 

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_SORTORDER, item.getSortorder());

    db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getId())});
}
```

I am trying to replicate the same method and database update in Room using a Dao method but with no luck.  What am I missing here?

```
public void resetSortIndexes() {

    int sortId = -1;
    int sortOrder = -1;
    int index = List.size();
    for (Card q : List) {
        q.setSortorder(index);
        sortOrder = q.getSortorder();
        sortId = q.getId();
        // update the Room database with the new, descending Sort index numbers.
        mCardViewModel.updateSortOrder(sortOrder, sortId);
        index--;
    }
}

ViewModel
...
public void updateSortOrder(int sortOrder, int sortId) {
    repository.updateSortOrder(sortOrder, sortId);
}

Repository
...
public void updateSortOrder(int sortOrder, int sortId) {
    try {
        new UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask(quickcardDao).execute(sortOrder, sortId).get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    private QuickcardDao asyncTaskDao;

    UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask(QuickcardDao dao) {
        asyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Integer... params) {

        asyncTaskDao.updateSortorder(params[0],params[1]);
        return null;
    }
}

Dao
...
@Query("UPDATE quickcards SET quickcardSortorder = :sortOrder WHERE quickcardId = :sortId")
void updateSortorder(int sortOrder, int sortId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out updating the RecyclerView's adapter was needed.  I added this method to the removeItem():

adapter.remove(quickcard);

```
Adapter
...
public void remove(Card item) {

    int position = mCards.indexOf(item);

    if (mCards.size()==0) {
        mCards.clear();
    }
    else if (position > -1) {
        mCards.remove(position);
    }
}

The updated (and correct) RecyclerView list size 
then allowed resetSortIndexes() to run properly.
```